Is there distance (metric) between two points on the hyperreal line in Nonstandard analysis?
As is known, there is distance between two points on the real line. It's obvious.
But if we imagine hyperreal line (see pic.) then we'll have infinitesimals and their corresponding points.

For example, we have two points: $0$ and $\epsilon$.
But can we talk about the distance between this points in context of hyperreal line? (I don't mean that distance is equal to $\epsilon$ but I mean metric $d(0,\epsilon)$).
Thanks.

Just defining $d(x,y) = |x-y|$ will satisfy all the requirements by the transfer principle. Do you want the distance to be a standard real?

Yes, we can - but with caveats.  When in doubt, consult the transfer principle.  If I have time I might write a full response later, but the basic idea boils down to: every first order property will be mirrored exactly in the expanded space, but some of the degrees-of-freedom will get "pruned" back off again (or "collapse") when you transfer back to the "standard' reals.

@Trebor some infinitesimal don't have concrete value (size). How to be?

What do you mean?  Every bounded nonstandard number has a well-defined nonstandard and standard magnitude.

@user3716267 We only know that such infinitesimals are less than every positive real numbers. That's all.

That's equivalent to having a standard magnitude of 0.  The nonstandard magnitude is equal to the (nonstandard) absolute value of the number.

@Mike_bb, you wrote: "some infinitesimal don't have concrete value (size)".  What do you mean exactly?  Can you elaborate?

@MikhailKatz It was my mistake. We have infinitesimal that doesn't have concrete value only in SIA*

By the transfer principle, the distance on $\mathbb R^\ast$ can be defined as usual: $$d(x,y)=|x-y|.$$  This idea can be used to give a new construction of the real numbers, bypassing both equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences and Dedekind cuts.  Thus, let $\mathbb L$ be the ring of limited hyperrationals.  Let $\mathbb I$ be the ring of hyperrational infinitesimals.  Then the quotient ring $\mathbb L/\mathbb I$ is isomorphic to the reals!
